# Anime material shade

Tags: materials

Do you know how to make exactly the same shading? I tried with toon material, but I did not manage to get such shading, I want the edges to be shaded like this, simply identical.[image]

Comment: are you using Eevee or Cycles? You could use vertex paint but it needs enough topology

Comment: I use eevee, I want to animate later so I'm afraid it will take me a long time in the cycle to render the video.